# Why was a readdir function added to POSIX library interface when there is a readdir kernel function?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I was surprised to discover the man pages having entries for two conflicting variants of `readdir`.

in READDIR(2), it specifically states you do not want to use it:

> This is not the function you are interested in.  Look at readdir(3) for the POSIX conforming C library interface.  This page documents the bare kernel system call interface, which is superseded by getdents(2).

I understand a function may become deprecated when another function comes along and does its job better, but I am not familiar with other cases of a userspace function coming in and replacing a kernel function of the same name. Is there a known reason it was chosen to go this route rather than coming up with a new function name (as the man page mentions `getdents` did when superseding `readdir`).

Comment: No Jedi mind tricks. When the man page tells you "These are not the droids you are looking for...", and then tells you where you can find them, it is pretty clear where you need to do. Other than for an historical aside, the old `readdir` and `getdents/getdents64` are not of much use.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm not questioning whether there's much point in using the old system call when writing code, but rather the reason a replacement came in using the same name, thus breaking any historical code that may have made use of the old one.  I've gotten the impression that backwards-compatibility has long been considered important to the C language and to Linux.  Granted this is more of a POSIX move than a move by the Linux Kernel or C Standard maintainers.

Comment: I gotcha, but in asking about why C no longer uses the directory read functions in use before POSIX, is kinda like asking why don't we use bag-phones anymore... It would really be an off-hand chance that someone with 2-decade old 1st hand knowledge could lay-out the exact considerations that led to the change, but absent that @R's answer captures in broad-brush why the old `readdir` is no longer used in favor of POSIX. `man 3 readdir` does a good job outlining the OS differences in `readdir` and why a POSIX standardization makes sense.

Comment: Why do you think the Linux kernel syscall predates the Unix/posix library function? It's only been around since the 70's...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's a shame we don't use bagphones anymore. `readdir(3)` is a horrendous inefficient interface which nobody is using properly, and there's no sane standard way to read directories in Unix.

Comment: I dunno, I kinda like the `opendir/readdir` approach. If you need to recursively walk the file tree, there is `ftw` and `nftw` that are a bit more flexible. But a recursive solution with `opendir/readdir` works just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programming interface, POSIX, is stable. You don't just go replacing functions in it unnecessarily because you want to implement the backend more efficiently. The Linux syscall `readdir` **never implemented the `readdir` function** because it has the wrong signature; it was an old, inefficient backend for implementing the `readdir` function. When a better backend came along, it was obsolete.

Comment: Can you put a little more detail into the assertion that it "never implemented the readdir function"?  And more to the point of the question, why was another function brought in with the *same name* rather than coming up with a name for the POSIX function that didn't interfere with already-existing code.

Comment: Your question is just a misunderstanding. POSIX predates Linux; it didn't define something conflicting with existing Linux usage. The Linux syscall was designed to be a mechanism for implementing the POSIX function, but wasn't a good mechanism.

Comment: So would it be more accurate to say that the Linux syscall `readdir` was a mistake, and in fixing they went with the POSIX `readdir`, but they had already shot themselves in the foot because they named the syscall the same as the pre-existing POSIX standard that they would then adopt?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: No. There was nothing that needed "fixing". The syscall was never an application programming interface. It was an interface between libc and the kernel. The `readdir` function, provided by libc and standardized in POSIX, goes back way further than Linux and must always have been available in Linux libc's, or portable software (including tools like GNU make, bash, ...) would not have worked on early Linux. There is no "shooting themselves in the foot". Syscalls are not in the same namespace as functions.

Comment: Actually, I suspect that's the misunderstanding behind your question - the idea that syscalls are in the same namespace as functions. That's only true if libc chooses to provide a wrapper for the syscall by the same name, that passes the exact arguments. These days there are very few such cases among the "traditional syscall" functions - most of them require additional work on the userspace side by libc, or use completely different syscalls for backends.

Answer (score 2):

You have it completely backwards: it's the library function `readdir(3)` which predates Linux and its `readdir(2)` system call, and not the reverse.

Naming the syscall that way was certainly a poor decision, and probably has a story behind it, but it's pretty much irrelevant now, as nobody is using it.

On Unix, directories used to be simple files formatted in a special way, and the system call interface through which they were read was just `read(2)` [1]. Later systems introduced system calls like `getdirentries` (44BSD) and `getdents` (SVR3), but they weren't willing or capable to standardize on an interface, so we're still stuck with the high level and broken [2] `readdir(3)` library function as the only standard interface for reading a directory.

[1] On some systems like BSD you can still `cat` a directory, at least when using the default filesystem (FFS).

[2] it's broken because it's not signal safe, and it returns `NULL` for both error and `EOF`, which means that the only way it could be safely used is by first setting `errno` to 0, and checking both its return value and `errno` afterwards. Yuck.